# A server that will accept 2 clients or more and will send a response from one client to the other client

Tags: c#, networking, server, p2p

I'm trying to make a 1v1 (pc vs pc) online game which is like Mortal Kombat, and I tried using TcpListener, but I'm not sure how to add another client so it will be 1v1, I'm also debating on if Peer to Peer would be better for that, but I haven't found any code examples of P2P so I didn't try getting into it yet.

```
 serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
        clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Server started");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        MessageBox.Show("Client connected!");
        byte[] response = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        networkStream.Read(response, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

That's the code I have which accepts one client but not sure what else to add, thought of a List, but I would have no idea how to send information for one client to the second one.

I need the server to fit a client vs client connection so it will send a message from one client to the other everytime I click a button.

Comment: why you use of tcp in game?

Comment: @amirstack I really don't know what to use, I think of P2P but I couldn't find any examples to implement that, what do you suggest? :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use of Udp protocol in game. in .Net you can use of Socket class or UdpClient class to implement your game, Socket class is harder but more flexible. Udp protocol is connectionless and you don't neccessary to connect clients to each other.
**Edit:**
you can get more information in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples)